# Alguien sabe como pasar el value de un combobox a otro para que realice la busqueda por ese ID ES EN JSP

Tags: java, jsp

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>ALUMNO</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="id">
        <%
            ArrayList<Alumno> lista = aldao.listarAlumno();
            for(Alumno e:lista){
        %>
            <option value="<%= e.getIdAlumno() %>"> <%=e.getA_nombres()+" "+e.getA_apellidos() %></option>
        <% } %>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label>CURSO</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="id_">
    <%
        int id=Integer.parseInt((String)request.getAttribute("id"));
        ArrayList<CursosAlumnos> lista2 = cadao.listarCursos(id);
        for(CursosAlumnos e:lista2){
        %>
            <option value="<%= e.getIdCurso() %>"> <%=e.getCu_nombres()%></option>
        <%}%>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, puede que le interese leer esto https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour, puede tratar de mejorar su pregunta mirando este link https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, es posible que su pregunta sea cerrada no se lo tome a mal. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Para pasar el valor seleccionado en un JComboBox a otro en JSP, puedes utilizar el atributo value de la etiqueta  que representa al JComboBox. Por ejemplo, si deseas pasar el valor seleccionado en un JComboBox llamado combo1 al JComboBox llamado combo2, puedes utilizar el siguiente código:

```
<!-- Primer JComboBox -->
<select name="combo1" id="combo1" onchange="document.getElementById('combo2').value = this.value">
  <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opción 3</option>
</select>

<!-- Segundo JComboBox -->
<select name="combo2" id="combo2">
  <option value="1">Opción 1</option>
  <option value="2">Opción 2</option>
  <option value="3">Opción 3</option>
</select>
```

En el código anterior, el JComboBox combo1 tiene un onchange que asigna el valor seleccionado en combo1 al atributo value del JComboBox combo2. De esta forma, cuando el usuario selecciona una opción en combo1, el valor seleccionado también se selecciona en combo2.